# Incomplete transfers of y-STRs from FamilyTreeDNA to ySearch?

Tags: dna, y-dna, familytreedna.com

I have used FamilyTreeDNA's transfer to [ySearch](http://www.ysearch.org) for each yDNA test I have had done and I just happened to notice today that for a yDNA-111 test, the transfer is incomplete, transferring only 67 markers even though ySearch.org has entries for many more.  I manually updated all the ones showing `-` except where they should be blank and corrected several that had a `0` value and now it shows I have 95 markers, still short of the 111 tested.

What is going on?  Is this a bug or is Family Tree DNA trying to make their private platform more valuable, or is something else going on?

Comment: I think it is good idea to write into support of FT-DNA and Ysearch simulraneously with the complete explanation of problem. Only after their reply we can make conclusions if it is bug or somebody's evil :-) will

Comment: I personally don't like the question titles in the form of "why doesn't [company] do X" because it makes me want to answer "I don't know, go ask them!" -- thus the title change.  I'm hoping the new question title will show up better in searches, too.

Comment: @JanMurphy Thanks Jan, great improvement to question title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ysearch](http://www.ysearch.org/) (and [Mitosearch](http://www.mitosearch.org/)) were ways to open up the FTDNA database to testers from other companies. Those willing to share their results could add them to those sites and match with non-FTDNA tests. This was at a time when Ancestry still sold Y-DNA and mtDNA tests. For clarification, these two sites are owned by Gene By Gene, FTDNA's parent company.

Since FTDNA is now the only major company still selling these tests, there's no real need to use these sites. That's why FTDNA stopped maintaining them. One of the problems is of course their lack of support to 111 markers. It's highly possible that they'll retire those services sooner rather than later.

At this point, I'd recommend to simply not bother uploading your Y-DNA and mtDNA tests outside of FTDNA. Other than Big-Y deep analysis, FTDNA itself has the largest number of tests.

Comment: Uploading to ySearch is still good because it allows a person to run a compare against you intentionally, there is no way in FTDNA to do this as it is oriented toward finding matches, not permitting an arbitrary compare of two known kits.  We use this feature on Wikitree.com.

Comment: @WilliamKF, I think in that case it might be easier for those persons to join the same FTDNA project, and then compare their results inside the DNA results tab. Primarily, since Ysearch doesn't support 111 markers. And from the looks of it, never will.

Comment: ySearch does support 111 for manual entry of the markers after 67.  There are millions of profiles on Wikitree, don't think it makes sense to create a project that covers all of Wikitree.